# Distribution of energies in canonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics

From what I understand, in a system $S$ described by a canonical ensemble, the probability that $S$ has energy $E$ is equal to $\frac{1}{Z}e^{-E/kT}$, where $T$ is the "temperature", $k$ the Boltzmann constant, and $Z$ the partition function.  I have two questions:

1) Is it obvious that $Z = kT$, since $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-E/kT}dE = kT$?

2) I'm failing to understand where the size of $S$ comes into play.  Is this energy distribution true whether $S$ is a system containing 1 or $10^{23}$ atoms?  I understand that the heat bath should be much larger than either of these, but don't understand how the size of the system doesn't play a role.

I think I'm missing something...

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67755/canonical-partition-function-what-assumption-is-at-work-here/67773#67773 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389683/deriving-the-boltzmann-distribution-using-the-information-entropy/389714#389714

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you're missing is that the probability is defined over *distinct states*, not just energies. So, what $Z$ is will depend on how that is defined.  For a single spin $1/2$ particle in a magnetic field there are exactly two states with energies $E_+$ and $E_-$, leading to the partition function $Z$ being
$$Z = \mathrm{e}^{-E_+/kT} + \mathrm{e}^{-E_-/kT}.$$

If you're talking about a classical particle in a box with volume $V$, then distinct states are those that have distinct position $\mathbf{x}$ and momentum $p$, producing the partition function
\begin{align}
     Z & = \int \mathrm{e}^{-p^2/(2mkT)} \operatorname{d}^3x\operatorname{d}^3p\\
      & = V  4\pi \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-p^2/(2mkT)} p^2
\operatorname{d}p.
\end{align}

Where the size comes into play is in both the volume, $V$, and the number of particles involved, $N$. When all of the individual particles are independent you can just raise $Z$ to the power $N$. When the particles aren't independent, you need to do more work to integrate/sum over the degrees of freedom available.

Comment: Even if the particle is a classical,  factor $1/h^3$ must be present ( David Tong compared this situation with  the vestigial effect, like the male nipple:)

Comment: Thanks! My understanding is that the canonical ensemble is derived by considering a small subsystem $S$ (with fixed $N$ and $V$) of a much larger one described by a microcanonical ensemble.  The phase space volume in which $S$ has energy $E_s$ is proportional to the phase space volume in which the remainder of the system has energy $E-E_s$, where $E$ is the total system energy.  Since phase space volume roughly increases exponentially with energy, a Taylor series expansion gives us the canonical distribution.  Doesn't this allow us to consider the probability distribution of energy?

Comment: @Menachem You still need the degeneracy of each energy level, often called $g$.

Comment: Wait, isn't the phase space volume of a given energy its degeneracy?  And doesn't the argument depend on the degeneracy increasing roughly exponentially with energy?

Comment: @Menachem I'm talking about the phase space volume of individual particles, and that grows like $4\pi p^2$. You're talking about the phase space volume of a system of particles, which grows combinatorically with $N$. Either way, the probability won't just be $Z^{-1} \mathrm{e}^{-E/kT}$, it's $Z^{-1} g(E) \mathrm{e}^{-E/kT}$.

Comment: Ok, I think I now have a better idea of what's going on.  Thank you!!